# Building a better cast system for Typescript

Tags: generics, typescript

I'm attempting to build a better casting model for Typescript to catch casting of invalid types. I would like to keep it as simple as possible so consumers don't have to provide unnecessary arguments, but it seems that Typescript Generics don't really allow for what I want to do...

Here's what I would like the function to look like:

```
module cast {
    export function to<T>(obj : any) : T {
        if (obj instanceof T) {
            return <T>obj;
        }

        throw new Error("Nope...");
    }
}

// Usage
var animal: Animal = getAnimal();
var mySnake = cast.to<Snake>(animal);
```

Unfortunately, as far as I know you can't reference a generic parameter within the function body, so the best I can do is:

```
module cast {
    export function to<T>(f : Function, obj : any) : T {
        if (obj instanceof f) {
            return <T>obj;
        }

        throw new Error("Nope...");
    }
}

// Usage
var animal: Animal = getAnimal();
var mySnake = cast.to<Snake>(Snake, animal);
```

This works, but I'm not a fan of the signature this creates. The parameters are redundant. Anyone know of a way to get this to work w/ referencing the type only once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Aha!** Figured it out...

```
module cast {

    export function to<T>(type: { new(any): T }, obj: any) {
        if (obj instanceof type) {
            return <T>obj;
        }

        throw new Error('Invalid cast');
    }

    export function as<T>(type: { new (any): T }, obj: any) {
        if (obj instanceof type) {
            return <T>obj;
        }

        return undefined;
    }
} 

// Usage
var animal: Animal = getAnimal();

 // if animal isn't a snake, then throw an exception
var mySnake = cast.to(Snake, animal);

 // if animal isn't a snake, then create a new instance
var other = cast.as(Snake, animal) || new Snake();
```

The generic T is inferred from the value of t, so it only has to be provided as the first argument and not in the generic parameter. Haven't really tested this beyond the Typescript Playground, but looks like it should work...

**Update:** Added 'as' function to return 'undefined' if cast is invalid.

Comment: I like this. might want to return null and not throw an exception. if i don't care about getting exception if it is not a snake i'll just cast it to <any> and hope for the best. what do you think?

Comment: I agree. I actually created a 2nd method that does this (see above edit)

Comment: IMHO undefined means that this var has no been set. null means 'i don't know what it is'.